# Customising Date Picker in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, datepicker

How can I customize a `UIDatePicker` to only show the month and year? There's an existing mode that shows the day, month, and year, but I'd like to get rid of the day portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you can't. `UIDatePicker` does not have any API for only showing years and months.

You therefore have 3 possible recourses:

1. Make your own out of a `UIPickerView`
2. Use a `UIDatePicker` in Date mode and just ignore the day portion
3. [File a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) asking for this capability and hope it gets added at some point

I vote for #1 and #3.

Answer (score 0):

It is not Possible to customize the date picker like you need in the nib file.You can set the mode in nib to get only date or time or both.In this case you need to format your date to the required format using **dateFormatter**.For this you can set the format to **"yyyy-MMM"**,which will returns you the year and month.

eg:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM"];
NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: how to use the dateformatter?  can u please add an example for that?